# How to use the jQuery validate plugin with strongly typed enumerations?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using a strongly typed view that lists an enumeration of objects, something like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Foo>

<table>
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Let's say `Foo` has a simple numeric property that I want to validate on the client side:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Required]
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Now the editor template for this object looks like this:

```
@model Foo

<tr>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Bar)</td>
</tr>
```

This works fine, except that the default model binder generates names like `[0].Bar`. However, `[` and `]` are invalid characters for the jQuery validate plugin and thus I am always receiving the following error whenever it tries to validate my input:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label[for='[0].Bar'], label[for='[0].Bar'] *, #[0].Bar

Is there any way to get the plugin to work while keeping my view bound to the model?

**Update**: I am using jQuery Validate and Microsoft's Unobstrusive Validation library (yep, the default ASP.NET MVC setup), so I am not directly writing any validation code at all, just if it's of interest!

Comment: See this:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)

Comment: Thanks! :) That explains the reason, but as I noted I am using unobstrusive validation to generate the validation rules and not writing any rules on my own...

Answer (score 1):

The [ and ] characters aren't strictly invalid for jQuery validate plugin. It's just a sloppy coding which doesn't account for possibility to have those chars in name/id.

There is even a GitHub issue [Handling ASP.NET MVC Input Arrays Exception](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1337) for this.

What I did is I took the code from issue (it has a small problem on it's own) and added this hack on my JavaScript initialization code:

```
$.validator.prototype.idOrName = function(element) {
    return this.groups[element.name]
        || (this.checkable(element)
            ? element.name
            : element.id || element.name)
        .replace("[", "\\[")
        .replace("]", "\\]");
}
```

That might not be pretiest or best solution but it works for me. At least till it's fixed in jQuery.

**No need to use this, as it's working with 1.13.1 (see issue above for discussion). Be warned, though I haven't checked myself, but ASP.NET MVC still could come bundled with 1.13.0**