# JQuery Unobtrusive Validation Get Error with MVC For loop

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

Hi I am trying to using  Unobtrusive Validation on my MVC application but got error.

**Jquery files referenced**

```
"~/Scripts/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js",
"~/Scripts/libs/jquery.browser.min.js", 
"~/Scripts/libs/bootstrap.min.js", 
"~/Scripts/libs/jquery.validate.min.js", 
"~/Scripts/libs/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js", 
"~/Scripts/libs/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class UserGroupNameMappingViewModel
{
    public string GeneralName { set; get; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This Field is required")]
    public string MappingName { set; get; }

    public UserGroupNameMappingViewModel() { }
}
```

**Client Side Form**

```
@model List<UserGroupNameMappingViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm()){

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="row form-group">

                @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].GeneralName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model[i].MappingName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].GeneralName)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].MappingName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].MappingName)
                <br />
            </div>
        }

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
    }
</div>
```

**Javascript Error I got(which thrown from Jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js)**

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label[for='[0].MappingName'], label[for='[0].MappingName'] *, #[0].MappingName-error
```

Please let me know your thoughts and Thanks!!

Comment: By the way I see <label for="" /> in viewsource looks like the label for does not work inside of for loop??

Comment: I wrote about hack which fixes this as an aswer to question [How to use the jQuery validate plugin with strongly typed enumerations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385833/how-to-use-the-jquery-validate-plugin-with-strongly-typed-enumerations/28041553#28041553)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution,

for each

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].MappingName)

I need give a good formatted id. for example

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].MappingName, new{id = "Model_MappingName_"+ @i})